# "<Association: >" needs to have a value for field "association" before this many-to-many relationship can be used: django error

Tags: django

I have seen a bit of similar threads here in SO but cant seem to solve it. Here is my model:

```
class Association(models.Model):
'''
For members declared as groups
'''
member=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='association_user')
name=models.CharField(max_length=50)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering=('name',)
```

The many-to-many relationship ended up creating, i think, a table under the hood with the following definitions:

```
association_id
user_id
```

I don't know if it is refering to the that field association nor how to add values to that table from my views.

my forms.py

```
class NewAssocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
'''
this is used to create a new form



'''
class Meta:
    model=Association
    fields=['name',]
    labels=['Assocation Name'),]
```

and my views.py:

```
@login_required
def make_new(request):
'''
Register a new association or corporate
'''

 if request.method=='POST':

    form=NewAssocationForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():

            new_association=form.save(commit=False)
            new_association.member=request.user


            new_association.save()


            #add a message then redirect

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/corporates/done/)

        else:
            form=NewAssocationForm(request.POST or None)



    else:
        form=NewAssocationForm(request.POST or None)

 return render(request, "association_new.html", locals())
```

I don't have a field named association in my model at all. I doubt it is constraint erorr cos i can insert records to the table from the shell without any issues.

Here is my traceback.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:9000/corporates/new/

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'welcome',
 'members',
 'corporates']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\agrigo\corporates\views.py" in make_new
  78.               new_association.member=request.user

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  499.         manager = self.__get__(instance)

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  476.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "D:\pyworks\agrigo\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  783.                                  (instance, self.source_field_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /corporates/new/
Exception Value: "<Association: North Side>" needs to have a value for field "association" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anyone who went through the long post. Apparently, I shouldn't specify user. So, deleting the line:

```
new_association.member=request.user
```

solved the issue. Makes sense; dumb me.